# AVAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:completionHandler never executes

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, photosframework

This question has been on here a few times, but I still don't see any answer anywhere. This has been killing me for a couple hours, I'd love some help here. I have the following code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:sourceVideoName];
NSDictionary *options = @{ AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey: @YES };

PHFetchResult *ph_fetch = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[url] options:nil];
PHAsset *ph_asset = [ph_fetch firstObject];

RCTLogInfo(@"Now we have PHAsset:\n%@", ph_asset);

[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:ph_asset options:options resultHandler:^(AVAsset * _Nullable asset, AVAudioMix * _Nullable audioMix, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {

  RCTLogInfo(@"Now we have AVAsset:\n%@", asset);

  NSError *error = nil;
  AVKeyValueStatus tracksStatus = [asset statusOfValueForKey:@"tracks" error:&error];

  switch (tracksStatus) {
    case AVKeyValueStatusCancelled:
      [self log:@"Early Tracks Canceled"];
      break;
    case AVKeyValueStatusLoading:
      [self log:@"Early Tracks Loading"];
      break;
    case AVKeyValueStatusLoaded:
      [self log:@"Early Tracks Loaded"];
      break;
    case AVKeyValueStatusFailed:
      [self log:@"Early Tracks Failed"];
      break;
    case AVKeyValueStatusUnknown:
      [self log:@"Early Tracks Unknown"];
      break;
  }

  [asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:@[@"tracks", @"duration"] completionHandler:^() {
    RCTLogInfo(@"We finally have a track callback???");
  }];

}];
```

And of course we never actually execute the final callback. I have no idea why and no idea how to fix it.

Comment: This may be an ARC issue.

Answer (score 0):

The comment on my question gave me insight into the answer. The basic version is that it appears that `asset` was being released from memory before the callback got to execute.

ARC gives stronger memory retention to properties, so this worked by adding to the interface definition in the header:

```
@property AVAsset *asset;
@property PHAsset *photoAsset;
```

and converting the code in the question above to:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:sourceVideoName];
NSDictionary *options = @{ AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey: @YES };

PHFetchResult *ph_fetch = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[url] options:nil];
[self setPhotoAsset:[ph_fetch firstObject]];

RCTLogInfo(@"Now we have instance PHAsset:\n%@", [self photoAsset]);

[[PHImageManager defaultManager] requestAVAssetForVideo:[self photoAsset] options:nil resultHandler:^(AVAsset * _Nullable localAsset, AVAudioMix * _Nullable audioMix, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {

  RCTLogInfo(@"Now we have local AVAsset:\n%@", localAsset);
  [self setAsset:localAsset];
  RCTLogInfo(@"Now we have instance AVAsset:\n%@", [self asset  ]);

  NSError *error = nil;
  AVKeyValueStatus tracksStatus = [[self asset] statusOfValueForKey:@"tracks" error:&error];

  switch (tracksStatus) {
    case AVKeyValueStatusCancelled:
      [self log:@"Early Tracks Canceled"];
      break;
    case AVKeyValueStatusLoading:
      [self log:@"Early Tracks Loading"];
      break;
    case AVKeyValueStatusLoaded:
      [self log:@"Early Tracks Loaded"];
      break;
    case AVKeyValueStatusFailed:
      [self log:@"Early Tracks Failed"];
      break;
    case AVKeyValueStatusUnknown:
      [self log:@"Early Tracks Unknown"];
      break;
  }

  [[self asset] loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:@[@"tracks", @"duration"] completionHandler:^() {
    RCTLogInfo(@"We finally have a track callback!!!");
  }];

}];
```